# select dno from employee where (select count(*) from employee where gender='f' group by dno) = 1 ;

Tags: mysql

The question is :You have a employee table.and you have to select the department where only one female is working.

table attribute are  fname,lname,ssn,gender,dno,salary.

my code is:

```
  select dno 
  from employee 
  where (select count(*)
                from employee 
                where gender='f' 
                group by dno) 
      = 1 ;
```

where i am wrong?

Comment: Your subquery must be **correlated**

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by with a `having` clause

```
select dno,count(*) as theCount
from employee
where gender='f'
group by dno
having theCount=1
```